# Unable to port C++ code that inserts into a trie to Rust due to multiple mutable borrows

Tags: rust, trie

I have the following C++ code:

```cpp
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Trie {
  bool eow;         //end of word
  char val; 
  vector<Trie> chd; //children

  void push_word(const string& word){
    Trie& trie = *this;
    for (char c: word){
      if (trie.chd.empty() || trie.chd.back().val != c) {
        trie.chd.push_back(Trie{false, c, vector<Trie>{}});
      }
      trie = trie.chd.back();
    }
    trie.eow = true;
  }
};
```

It's a trie for strings. `push_word` is supposed to only accept strings that are lexicographically greater than any word already contained in the trie; this way the search for the correct child can be skipped at each node. In other words, this allows us to efficiently construct a trie from a sorted vector of words:

```cpp
Trie from_sorted_vector(const vector<string>& words){
  Trie trie{false, '\0', vector<Trie>{}};
  for (const auto& word: words) {
    trie.push_word(word);
  }
  return trie;
}
```

I have the following in Rust:

```
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug, Clone)]
struct Trie {
    eow: bool,
    val: char,
    chd: Vec<Trie>,
}

impl Trie {
    fn new(eow: bool, val: char, chd: Vec<Trie>) -> Trie {
        Trie {
            eow: eow,
            val: val,
            chd: chd,
        }
    }

    fn push_word(&mut self, word: &String) {
        let mut trie = self;
        for c in word.chars() {
            // ???
        }
    }
}
```

I can't implement `push_word` in an analogous manner to C++. I always get two mutable borrows or one immutable and one mutable borrow, for `trie` or `trie.chd`, or the last element of `trie.chd`. I'd like to get some directions as to how this should be done.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

See This One Weird Trick To Beat The Borrow Checker: Compilers Hate It.

```
#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug, Clone)]
struct Trie {
    eow: bool,
    val: char,
    chd: Vec<Trie>,
}

impl Trie {
    fn new(eow: bool, val: char, chd: Vec<Trie>) -> Trie {
        Trie {
            eow: eow,
            val: val,
            chd: chd,
        }
    }

    fn push_word(&mut self, word: &String) {
        let mut trie = self;
        for c in word.chars() {
            if trie.chd.last().map_or(true, |t| t.val != c) {
                trie.chd.push(Trie::new(false, c, vec![]))
            }

            let tmp = trie; // *
            trie = tmp.chd.last_mut().unwrap();
        }

        trie.eow = true;
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

It is the introduction of the line marked `*` that makes this work. The compiler isn't yet smart enough to see that the mutable sub-borrow of `trie` via `last_mut` is *replacing* the mutable borrow of `trie`. If it understood this, it would accept the obvious code `trie = trie.chd.last_mut().unwrap();`, but for the moment the programmer has to manually make this guarantee by first moving the borrow out of `trie` and then one is free to reassign. This moves the ownership of the borrow around in a way the compiler can understand.

This is covered by [issue #10520](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/10520).

Comment: That first sentence earned an upvote, I’m sad to say…

Comment: First sentence negated what would have been an up-vote from me.

Comment: @nathanchere, I hope it helped you, even if you didn't like how I framed it! :)

Answer (score 8):

The original code works once [non-lexical lifetimes](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50251487/155423) are enabled:

```
#![feature(nll)]

#[derive(Eq, PartialEq, Debug, Clone)]
struct Trie {
    eow: bool,
    val: char,
    chd: Vec<Trie>,
}

impl Trie {
    fn new(eow: bool, val: char, chd: Vec<Trie>) -> Trie {
        Trie { eow, val, chd }
    }

    fn push_word(&mut self, word: &str) {
        let mut trie = self;
        for c in word.chars() {
            if trie.chd.last().map_or(true, |t| t.val != c) {
                trie.chd.push(Trie::new(false, c, vec![]))
            }

            trie = trie.chd.last_mut().unwrap();
        }

        trie.eow = true;
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

NLL increases the precision of the compiler's borrow checker, allowing it to see that the mutable borrow is no longer used.

---

Until NLL is enabled by default, there is a slightly more streamlined method that accomplishes the same as [huon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27083650/155423), but without the need of an explicit temporary variable:

```
fn push_word(&mut self, word: &String) {
    let mut trie = self;
    for c in word.chars() {
        if trie.chd.last().map_or(true, |t| t.val != c) {
            trie.chd.push(Trie::new(false, c, vec![]))
        }

        trie = { trie }.chd.last_mut().unwrap(); // Here
    }

    trie.eow = true;
}
```

We enclose the "old" trie in a block, which transfers ownership, creating an unnamed temporary.